# empty EdixText to String conversion

Tags: android

I am executing a runtime command from Button with text from EditText.
But I dont want to execute empty command.

```
EditText et = (EditText) findviewbyid(R.id.et)
if (et.toString()!=null | et.toString()!=""){
    //executing cammand
}
```

I have not set any text to EditText in XML.
but when clicking button on empty EditText it executing command.

Comment: use et.getText().toString()

Comment: Did you even try to search it anywhere? I don't think so.

Comment: `editText.getText().toString()` will never return `null`, but it may return an empty `String`. You can check it either with one of the other suggested answers, or with the more longwinded `if (editText.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))`

Answer (score 2):

`et` is the `EditText`. Its never `null`. You have to check the text entered in the `EditText`. Like this

```
EditText et = (EditText) findviewbyid(R.id.et)
if (!et.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
    //executing cammand
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check your edittext contain data or not by using this :

```
if (!et.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
    //executing cammand
}
```